# Regex validation including HTML encoded characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a string (PHP & Regex) and I want option A to validate successfully but option B to not validate at all:

```
a) fsadgfsd!^_-@<>&lt; 
            OR
   fsadgfsd!^_-@<>&gt;&lt;


b) fsadgfsd!^_-@<>&; 
          OR 
   fsadgfsd!^_-@<>;&&;
```

So far I have this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \!\^\_\@\<\>-]+$/
```

Which is validating everything for me except for the HTML encoded substrings of < and > and I'm hitting a brick wall with it at this stage, any help greatly appreciated.

Basically, in addition to my existing regex which is matching my special characters, I also need to be able to match the exact substrings of either < or > but not match the & or ; character on their own.

Due to restrictions in the code that I'm using, I'm not in a positon to be able to decode the data before validating it either...

Comment: Both the options will not validate as they contain ampersand and semi-colon

Comment: That's where I think I was falling short, I could find no way to validate the & and ; characters ONLY if they were a part of either &lt; or &gt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$regex = '/^[\w !\^@<>-]+$/';


$string = 'fsadgfsd!^_-@<>&gt;&lt;';
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
if (preg_match($regex, $string))
    echo 'ok';
// echo ok


$string = 'fsadgfsd!^_-@<>;&&;';
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
if (preg_match($regex, $string))
    echo 'ok';
// echo nothing
```

\w is a shortcut for [a-zA-Z0-9_]

EDIT: without html_entity_decode

```
$regex = '/^([\w !\^@<>-]*(&[glt]+;)*)+$/';


$string = 'fsadgfsd!^_-@<>&gt;&lt;';
if (preg_match($regex, $string))
    echo 'ok';
// echo ok
echo '-------------';

$string = 'fsadgfsd!^_-@<>;&&;';
if (preg_match($regex, $string))
    echo 'ok';
// echo nothing
```

Comment: Hey Louis, maybe my question wasn't as descriptive as it could have been. I need to be able to also match the exact substrings of either &lt; or &gt; but not match the & or ; character on their own. I'll update the question to reflect this

Comment: hey Louis, cheers for the update, my question yet again has fallen short in giving the full story - I wish I could decode the data but I'm using FuelPHP and the regular expression is entered at the same time the field is created. The way that the encoding is handled I unfortunately have no way of decoding the string before validating it.